# How do I list folder contents in a blob container?

Tags: c#, listbox, azure-blob-storage

I have code that lists the blobs and folders of a container to an asp.net listBox. On double-click of a listItem that's a folder, the contents of the folder go to the listBox. The problem is that such does not work on any folder after the first layer, and the listBox becomes empty instead.

My contention is that my code has the referenced directory being within the container, and since the subfolder isn't directly inside the container, it is not recognized and the listBox comes up empty.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "expand")
        {

            List<string> ListBlobsInFolder()
            {

                List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
                CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("MYCONNECTIONSTRING");
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("testcontainer");
                ListItem listItem = lboxLogs.SelectedItem;
                CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(listItem.ToString());
                IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> blobList = directory.ListBlobs();
                    foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobList)
                    {
                        blobs.Add(string.Format("{0}", item.Uri.Segments.Last()));
                    }
                return blobs;

                //IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> subDirectoryList = subDirectory.ListBlobs();
            }

            try
            {
                if (lboxLogs.SelectedItem.ToString().EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        lboxLogs.DataSource = ListBlobsInFolder();
                        lboxLogs.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (System.NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }            
        lboxLogs.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lboxLogs, "expand"));
    }
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem such that when I double-click, the directory reference will be from within the container when necessary, and within another folder when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to the folder structure of Azure blobs, it is currently a virtual folder, the way to access anything within those virtual folders, it to append the Virtual directory's name to the blob within it, example:

```
  ['Virtual-Folder/2019-02-06 10_43_04-Access Control - Microsoft Azure.png', 'Virtual-Folder/Boards.png', 'storage2.gif']
```

When listing the list of blobs within a container containing a virtual folder named: "Virtual-Folder", a blob that's within it would be reachable via this name: "'Virtual-Folder/Boards.png'" if i try calling only "Boards.png" it will not work.

I also wrote some examples in github using python SDK, feel free to peak at the code examples [here](https://github.com/adamsmith0016/Azure-storage)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The thing is I can access the virtual folder immediately listed in the container, but I don't know how to access any folder within that folder. I'm requesting blobs from a remote device, which uploads the blobs to the container within 2 folders by default. So, I cannot hard-code any blob names.

Comment: you mean listing the content of the virtual folder ? If you want to do that, you'll have to list the content of the container, this will return the content of all virtual folders.

Comment: Got it - I just used useFlatBlobListing: true to circumvent the issue. Thanks again.